# Oracle - ORA-01722: número inválido

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Podem me ajudar com esse erro? Geralmente dá número inválido quando não coloco aspas simples. Tentei converter pra number (apesar de coluna ser varchar2), mas erro persiste

```
DECLARE

  TYPE cVetor IS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER(30);

  V_DATA DATE;

  carnes cVetor := cVetor('2023621240781',' 2012321237746', '20192321236243', '2019612128378');

    BEGIN

        V_DATA := TO_DATE('19/01/2019 03:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

        FOR i in 1..carnes.count LOOP

          BEGIN


          UPDATE OW.CARNE CAR
             SET CAR.DT_EMISSAO       = V_DATA,
                 CAR.DT_GERACAO       = V_DATA,
                 CAR.DT_BAIXA         = V_DATA,
                 CAR.DT_BAIXA_SISTEMA = V_DATA
           WHERE CAR.TXT_NOSSO_NUMERO = carnes(i); --VARCHAR2(15)

          UPDATE OW.COBRANCA COB
             SET COB.DT_EMISSAO       = V_DATA,
                 COB.DT_GERACAO       = V_DATA,
                 COB.DT_BAIXA         = V_DATA,
                 COB.DT_BAIXA_SISTEMA = V_DATA
           WHERE COB.TXT_NOSSO_NUMERO = carnes(i); --VARCHAR(15)
          COMMIT;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Carnê' || carnes(i) || 'atualizado');

        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERRO CARNE ' || carnes(i) || sqlerrm);
       END;
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
COB.TXT_NOSSO_NUMERO = to_char(carnes(i));
```

Tenta assim

Comment: funcionou, obrigada

Comment: não tem de quê =D